# Xampp reports "Apache shutdown unexpectedly" error

Tags: apache, xampp

Xampp we ran a while Apache crashes, but do not know the cause.

```
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
8:16:54 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: we are running the software for the system, changed ports, we have large queries suspected prolonged hanging apache

Comment: As said in the Log: `This may be due to a blocked port`. This may be the problem as you mentioned a port-change.

Comment: but we changed ports 80 and 443, it is not an error that occasionally she start stop and start is faulty functioning normally dongk. We give apache boot in Service

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when I tried to get Apache to start in XAMPP. Most answers I came across had to do with going into "Services" and making the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" Stop. However, when I looked for it in "Services" (Windows 10) it wasn't there, so I tried another route and it worked. Here are the steps I took:

1. From the XAMPP Control Panel, click "config" for Apache, and access (httpd.conf)
2. Locate the following:
   "#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 #Listen 80" (the "#Listen 80" will be on a second line, for some reason Stack Overflow distorts the text when I duplicate it here.
3. Change the second line to "Listen 8080"
4. Drop down to "ServerName localhost: 80" & change it to "ServerName localhost: 8080"
5. Save and Close the file
6. From the XAMPP Control Panel, click "config" for Apache, and access (httpd-ssl.conf)
7. Locate the following: "Listen 443" & change it to "Listen 4433"
8. Drop down to "," change it to ""
9. Save and Close the file.

Now, when you click for Apache to start, it should turn green and all will be well. If this doesn't help try the popular fix of locating the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and right click to "Stop" it - it didn't work for me, but it might work for you. I really hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: What's step #8 for? about deleting a comma? I don't get it, although I did seem to fix my issue with the other steps you detailed.

Answer (score 2):

try this on PowerShell

```
netstat -na | Select-String "80"
```

this will help out identifying if any service is using port 80 or not. to identify what using it try following on

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess
```

this will bring up the Id of process. Most of the case on newly installed windows boxes, it might be "World Wide Web" service. for some reason I am not able to spot it in services console. Anyway following will help to stop it.

```
sc stop w3svc
```

If it is there it would be stopped and you can verify buy running above command again.

EDIT: 
you may have [BatchCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/branchcache/branchcach) service running which requests http.sys service to register port 80 when running in distributed mode. there is a way to [change the port](https://2pintsoftware.com/faq-items/can-change-branchcache-port-distributed-mode/) for this but I haven't tried instead i prefer to stop. Probably stopping through services will not work so using following commnd on powershell may help

```
Disable-BC
```

If you like to know other command of BranchCache use following command

```
Get-Command -Module BranchCache
```

There are some other articles proposing to stop http.sys service which may or may not be desired as per your circumstances [see what each of the depended services does](https://superuser.com/a/1439440/54380)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set virtual host in another drive (such as external harddrive) and you disconnect it.
Connect it again and change **DoucumentRoot** and **Directtory** to the right location.

file httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "E:/somefolder"
    ServerName myweb.local
    ServerAlias www.myweb.local
    <Directory "E:/somefolder">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
        Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because your Xampp default port 80 is already used by another server like Oracle or Tomcat web server,

If you want step by step support please [Click Here](http://developersocean.com/2017/05/13/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port/)