# I Cannot Locate World Wide Web Publishing Service in Services on Windows 10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

Please bear with me, I'm not 100% tech savvy - yet. When I try to run XAMPP (in order to experiment with local WordPress), everything runs except Apache. All the current data on the issue points me to stop the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" from "Services" in Windows 10.

However, I have found that the World Wide Web Publishing Service is missing from services, I have looked in both the Standard and Extended list, and it simply isn't there, neither is the variant "W3SVC."

[image: Screenshot of "Services"]

I have also tried an entire search of my pc for both phrases and I came up empty. Please assist, I'm stuck and I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: NVM, I fixed the Apache/XAMPP issue myself without locating the "World Wide Web Publishing Service."

Comment: post your fix in an answer

Comment: I posted the full answer to this question to another user, since I cannot answer my own question (this is my first attempt at using SO) Unfortunately, the entire answer cannot fit here, but if you follow this link you'll be able to see the full fix:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244195/xampp-apache/33984839#33984839   I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

1. go to start -> programs and features -> turn Windows features on or off and enable: 
   i. Internet Information Services 
   ii. Internet Information Services Hostable Web Core.
2. Refresh Services
3. Done!

Comment: programs and features option is in start > settings > control panel

Answer (score 0):

To install the World Wide Web Publishing Service

- On the Start menu, select Settings, Control Panel, and then click Add
  or Remove Programs
- Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
- In the
  Components list, select the Application Server check box, and then
  click Details.
- Select Internet Information Services Manager, and then
  click Details.
- Select World Wide Web Service, and then select the
  check box.
- Click OK two times to return to the Components list, and
  then click Next.
- Click Finish when the IIS service is installed.

For more information, see...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997600(v=exchg.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

"....everything runs except Apache"

**Answer :**
Nevermind if you don't have "Service World Wide Web Http" in your inbound FireWall Rules list.
**Just add a New Incoming traffic Rule to your List :**
- Name and path of your Application (in your case : "Apache")
- Authorise
Done.