# Live view not rendering in Dreamweaver CS6 for PHP files

Tags: php, localhost

Using XAMPP which is set up correctly for Dreamweaver CS6 when selecting live view I show page not found or the symbol for PHP where the words `hello world` would be.

Using Chrome and enter Localhost it returns:

> Not Found
>   HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

XAMPP set up:

- Server Nme: Test Site
- Connect Using: Local/Network
- Server Folder: C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite\
- WEB URL: http://localhost/TestSite/

Folders in file explorer: `C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite`

Local Sie Folder: `C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite\`

The code using for testing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Intended Output:

> My first PHP page

Comment: The output should be Hello World, This is my first PHP page, Hello World.

Comment: What's the name of the file you saved with the HTML & PHP in it?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\TestSite\test.php

Comment: And when you enter localhost/TestSite/test.php in your browser you get a 404 error?

Comment: This is what I receive: Not Found
HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: Based on that description, it sounds like your problem is in your XAMPP set up, not php. I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to change the Web URL in Dreamweaver Site Manager:

From
 http://localhost/TestSite/
To
 http://localhost8080/TestSite/

Since the original port 80 was used when the XAMPP server was installed which appears to be a common issue.

See:
[Xampp, Apache :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244195/xampp-apache)